# Restrict a decimal(18, 8) to values above 1.00

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in MSSQL database with a column type: decimal(18, 8)
I would like to limit it to only values above 1.00

So if there's a value below 1.00 then it will give an error.

Thanks

Comment: Add a [`CHECK` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) to the column, eg `CHECK (SomeColumn > 1.0 )`

Comment: THINK about your goal and what you are asking. Is 1.001 OK? That is greater than 1.00. How about 1.00000001?

Comment: SMor, I think I said it pretty clearly.. 1.001 is higher than 1.00, that means it's ok. I will try the Constraint and let you know! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [CHECK constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017), like this

```
CONSTRAINT [CHK_SomeTable_SomeColumn]   
   CHECK ([SomeColumn] >= 1.00);
```

---

If you only want the constraint to apply in certain conditions you could write,

```
CONSTRAINT [CHK_SomeTable_CurrencyID_SomeColumn]   
   CHECK ([CurrencyID] <> N'USD' OR [SomeColumn] >= 1.00);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. However, I need to add a WHERE clause and can't find the syntax.

It should be:

CHECK (RateToSec > 1) WHERE (CurrencyID = N'USD')

Comment: @whatever61, extended the answer